# Excel bar chart does not display to correct y-axis value

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a bar chart wherein I display one set of data as a clustered bar and another data set as a line.  All is well except the actual bars do not extend so as to display the proper value on the y-axis.  The data is correct and returns as correct when one hovers over the bar.  For instance, a value of 85 yields a data label as 85, but the actual bar displays to about 84 or 84.5.  Is there an answer to this?

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to see the data that corresponds to this chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely rounding going on. Number of digits on the chart should correspond to the formatting of the cell.

Comment: Format/rounding was the key.  Thank you.